# Worksheet ranges doesn't contain newly created range

Tags: aspose-cells

In my current project I want to find the ranges of a worksheet, but the `lookupWorksheet.Cells.Ranges` property contains no elements while Workbook.Worksheets.GetNamedRanges() does.

My initial code was

```
var sheetRanges = worksheet.Cells.Ranges.Cast<Range>().ToList();
```

I had to change it to the more complicated

```
var sheetRanges = worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets.GetNamedRanges();
if (sheetRanges != null) {
    sheetRanges = sheetRanges.Where(range => range.Worksheet == worksheet).ToArray();
}
```

Does it matter that the range was created by code earlier?
Do I have to 'commit' that range somewhere maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Please note, you will have to set the **Range.Name** property to make your range appear in the **Workbook.Worksheets.GetNamedRanges()** method.

Please see the following code and it comments. It creates a range A1:A3 and it appears inside the collection returned by GetNamedRanges() method

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
Range range = worksheet.Cells.CreateRange("A1:A3");
range.Name = "MyRange";

//Now your range will appear inside this collection
var sheetRanges = worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets.GetNamedRanges();

Console.WriteLine(sheetRanges[0]);
```

Here is the console output of the above code for your reference.

```
Aspose.Cells.Range [ MyRange : Sheet1!A1:A3 ]
```

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: I did assign a name and it already shows up in GetNamedRanges, but I want it to show up in worksheet.Cells.Ranges

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. You need to use AddRange() method to add Range inside the Ranges collection. Please check my second answer for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **Worksheet.Cells.AddRange()** method to add range inside the **Worksheet.Cells.Ranges** collection.

Please see the following sample code for your reference.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

Range range = worksheet.Cells.CreateRange("A1:A3");

worksheet.Cells.AddRange(range);

Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cells.Ranges[0]);
```